# Same phone shows different locations using Life360 vs Google Maps

Tags: gps, geolocation, google-location-history

My mother's cellphone shows her in two different cities on the same day. The Life360 app shows she's in Chicago, while the Google Location history shows she's in Alabama.

I think she might have given her old phone to my niece. Could both phones share location data even with different SIM cards?

Answer (score 0):

Before giving the old phone away, did she wipe it? Otherwise, if she is still logged-in to that phone via Google, it's gonna think she has two phones and will show the location of both.

Comment: OK, I see, well I changed moms Google password on her new phone, so...hopefully that should log out the old phone, wdyt?

Comment: Yeah the other phone will be prompted to enter the new password and if you dont, it should log it out.